# How do I remove an already set attribute and replace with another in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, attributes, click, addeventlistener, setattribute

I added an attribute to a div I created, now I want to remove this attribute and replace with another once listen to a click event. How do I do that?

I tried using the remove attribute but I don't seem to understand why it's not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check if below example helps you.
- You can skip the else condition in script if you only need to remove the attribute on click.

  ```
   <div align="center" id="div1"><p>Example</p></div>
   <button  onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

   <script>
   function myFunction() { 
      var x = document.getElementById("div1"); 
      if (x.hasAttribute("align")) { 
          x.removeAttribute("align");  
      }else{ 
          x.setAttribute("align", "right");
      } 
   }
   </script>
  ```